# z-score of all cells in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cell, normalization

I have matrices of different size in 35 cells such that 
[image]

The variable name is `population`.

How can I find a z score that uses all values in all cells? The mean and the standard deviation is mean and s.d. of all values in the `population` variable. I don't want to normalize each cell by itself.

I'm using Matlab 2017a, so some commands for 2019b are not working, either.

Comment: What is the mean of your data? a 14x1? A scalar? something else? I guess sticking everything together to a 14xn matrix, then apply the `zscore` function and finally slice it up into individual cells would do what you want?

Comment: When I apply cellfun(@mean, population) it's a matrix of 35x14. What you said is what I want but after 20th cell, the sizes of the matrices change. Number of rows become 19.

Comment: The question is not what `mean` returns. The question was more about the math behind your question. You wrote "The mean and the standard deviation is mean and s.d. of all values in the population variable." What does this mean? Is the mean supposed to be a single scalar value?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for one scalar value.

Comment: A solution would be: 1) Put all values together into a single vector 2) Calculate mu and std using this vector 3) apply X=(X-mu) ./ std to each of the matrices.